# G1 GC allocated memory is more than heap size

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, g1gc, java-heap

I change GC for application server. Now I use G1 GC.  I have 30 GB  RAM. For initial testing I set only Xms and Xmx values to be the same **23040** mb.

Settings I use:

```
 -Xms23040m -Xmx23040m  -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MetaspaceSize=512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1536m
```

I have interesting GCEasy Metrics  if I use G1 GC.

```
   Generation         | Allocated | Peak
   Young Gen          | 13.38     | 3.37
   Old Gen            | 21.17     | 485mb
   Meta Space         | 1.5       | n/a
   Young + old + Meta | 23.78     | 13.61
```

Total is  **36.05 GB** How come?  GCEasy Diagram [link is here.](https://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=YXJjaGl2ZWQvMjAyMi8wMS8yMC8tLWFwaS1iN2NmNjNhOC02MjVmLTRjNDEtODY3Ny1iZDYwYWNhOTJhYjAudHh0&channel=API)

I don't understand why allocated Memory is more than Max heap size?

GC initial Log:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.282-b08) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_282-b08), built on Jan 20 2021 11:56:52 by "jenkins" with gcc 7.5.0
Memory: 4k page, physical 31389860k(23816948k free), swap 0k(0k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:GCLogFileSize=3145728 -XX:InitialHeapSize=23923261440 -XX:MaxHeapSize=23923261440 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1610612736 -XX:MetaspaceSize=536870912 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
```

GC Pause log:

```
    2022-01-19T08:18:40.340-0500: 45739.624: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.0675291 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 42.0 ms, GC Workers: 1]
      [GC Worker Start (ms):  45739624.2]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms):  10.8]
      [Update RS (ms):  5.1]
         [Processed Buffers:  76]
      [Scan RS (ms):  2.1]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms):  2.9]
      [Object Copy (ms):  21.0]
      [Termination (ms):  0.0]
         [Termination Attempts:  1]
      [GC Worker Other (ms):  0.0]
      [GC Worker Total (ms):  41.9]
      [GC Worker End (ms):  45739666.1]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 5.8 ms]
   [Other: 19.7 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 16.8 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.1 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 2.3 ms]
   [Eden: 13632.0M(13632.0M)->0.0B(13632.0M) Survivors: 57344.0K->57344.0K Heap: 13933.2M(22816.0M)->307.2M(22816.0M)]
 [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs]
```

Does it mean that GCEasy.io has bug to show correct metrics? I do not have similar issues when I use **Parallel GC**. (Allocated memory is **not** more than Xmx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your JVM parameters ,the number is byte. 23923261440(byte) = 22815(Mb) = 22.28(Gb)

```
-XX:InitialHeapSize=23923261440
-XX:MaxHeapSize=23923261440
```

By default, the space of G1's `Young Gen` and `Old Gen` is not fixed.From the `Interactive Graphs` column of the GCEasy page you shared,
I have organized the following information in a timeline.

| GC Times | Young Gen(Mb) | Old Gen(Mb) | Total(Mb) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1232 | 21584 | 22816 |
| Fifth | 1136 | 21680 | 22816 |
| 33th | 5384 | 17432 | 22816 |
| 35th | 1200 | 21616 | 22816 |
| 53th | 13696 | 9120 | 22816 |
| Last | 13688 | 9128 | 22816 |

The following conclusions can be drawn from the table above:

1. If `-Xms` is set and consistent with `-Xmx`, then `Young Gen` plus `Old Gen` will be a fixed value.
2. The `Young Gen` space is always changing, sometimes increasing and sometimes decreasing. `old Gen` is the opposite.

---

In G1, the space of `Young Gen` is always changing after GC, the space of `Young Gen` in `Parallel GC` is always fixed.
Therefore, GCEasy cannot use a unique value to represent the allocation space of each `gen` of G1, so it chooses to take each `Gen`
The maximum value during application running. According to the table above, the space is calculated as follows:

- The maximum value of `Young Gen` is: 13696(Mb) = 13.375(Gb) ≈ 13.38(Gb)
- The maximum value of `Old Gen` is: 21680(Mb) = 21.171(Gb) ≈ 21.17(Gb)

The approximation of the two values exactly matches the table below.

| Generation | Allocated | Peak |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Young Gen | 13.38 | 3.37 |
| Old Gen | 21.17 | 485mb |
| Meta Space | 1.5 | n/a |
| Young + old + Meta | 23.78 | 13.61 |

Answer (score 0):

The allocated size listed in that table includes [Metaspace](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Metaspace). Metaspace is memory pool separate from the java object heap. Therefore the sum of heap and metaspace can exceed the maximum heap size.

> ```
>  [Eden: 13632.0M(13632.0M)->0.0B(13632.0M) Survivors: 57344.0K->57344.0K Heap: 13933.2M(22816.0M)->307.2M(22816.0M)]
> ```

This indicates that the overall heap size (all generations) was at ~22GB, which is within the max heap limit. Perhaps gceasy is mistaking the total heap size as old generation?

Comment: Meta Space is only 1.5 GB. But OG + YG = 21.17 GB + 13.38 GB = 34.55 GB.  I don't get it. Xmx = 22GB. Why OG+ YG is bigger?

Comment: RAM is only 30 GB. I don't get why OG+YG allocated memory is 34.5 GB

Comment: It isn't. Look at the "Young + old + Meta" number. young and old cannot be larger than that. The table is wrong. A+B <= A+B+C

Comment: It should further raise your suspicion when “peek” is smaller than the alleged “allocated” amount.

Comment: Yep. GCEasy has problems to show up metrics correctly. Dynatrace works fine.